# .NET 7 Minimal API: Can not authenticate with Swagger, but with Postman

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have a minimal web API in .NET 7. When testing the API via Swagger, I get a 401-Error not authorized.

The nuget packages are included in the following versions:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer -> 7.0.5
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore -> 6.5.0

I have the following settings:

```cs
var securityScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
    Name = "Authorization",
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
    Scheme = "Bearer",
    BearerFormat = "JWT",
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"Bearer 12345abcdef\"",
};
var securityReq = new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
{
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id = "bearerAuth"
            },
            Name = "Bearer",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header
        },
        Array.Empty<string>()
    }
};
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1",
        new OpenApiInfo
        {
            Version = "v1"
        });

    var xmlFilename = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    options.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFilename));

    options.EnableAnnotations();
    options.DocInclusionPredicate((name, api) => true);
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", securityScheme);
    options.AddSecurityRequirement(securityReq);
});
```

```cs
builder.Services.AddOptions<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .Configure<IStoreManager>(
        (options, storeManager) => options.TokenValidationParameters =
            new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                IssuerSigningKey = GetKeyFromAmagnoCertificate(storeManager),
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            });
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(
    options =>
    {
        var requiredClaim = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .RequireClaim(IdentityData.PermissionClaimName, "GroupDocumentRecognitionSettings");

        options.AddPolicy(IdentityData.PermissionPolicyName, requiredClaim.Build());

        options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
    });
```

Before mapping the endpoints there are is:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

The `MapGet()` has a `.RequireAuthorization(IdentityData.PermissionPolicyName)` at the end.

So when I hit the Authorize button in Swagger, I enter "Bearer myToken" and then call the Get route. Here I get a 401. If I make the same call with Postman, it works.

Am I missing something in the Swagger configuration that I'm overlooking? Has anyone else had this problem at some point?

Comment: Did you figure it out @BenGeba ??